# WebDriver - impossible switch from FFDriver to ChromeDriver or IEDriver

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm trying to create a big selenium suite in Firefox but I'm also wondering how difficult would be made all these tests working in the Chrome or IE even because the page is simply rendered in a different manner and is already difficult link them and make the other drivers working.

Any suggestion or experience to share about? Thanks in advance, Lorenzo.

Answer (score 2):

In general this kind of scenario is a good candidate for the Template pattern.  Combine that with the Page Object pattern since you are using Webdriver and you should be able to minimize your duplicated code.

The idea is that you would create some kind of helper object that performs commonly used steps.  Most of the steps are the same across browsers.  But since your UI changes depending on the browser, certain actions will require custom steps.  So you will have concrete implementations that inherit most of the steps from the abstract base but implement specific functionality where the UI differences make it impossible to reuse the same base code.

For example, on the page where you have your two input boxes, your firefox implementation of the required action would have two clicks while your Chrome implementation will just have one.  The login and navigation steps will (theoretically) be the same and can be shared via the base class.

You configure your helper objects (page factory, etc) in your Testing framework's SetUp method. Your tests call the appropriate methods on the helper objects to perform the actions and then you verify the results.

*References:*

- Template Pattern - http://www.oodesign.com/template-method-pattern.html
- Page Object Pattern - http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects

Answer (score 0):

I have found Selenium is not very cross-browser friendly at all. Many little quirks prevent a single test from running smoothly on all supported browsers. A lot of course depends on how complex the pages being tested are and how complex the testing code is (I'm assuming this is being coded and not recorded).

A possible solution is to create a layer of abstraction on top of the WebDrivers that exposes common actions while normalizing the behavior depending on the browser instance (think how jQuery works).

Comment: This has not been my experience at all. It might be useful if you provided concrete examples of the "little quirks [that] prevent a single test from running smoothly".

Comment: "depends on how complex the pages being tested are". I don't have an example with me (concrete examples have been submitted as bug reports), but I have a large set of tests that pass in IE8 but not in Firefox or Chrome so it is not my imagination or a frivolous observation.

Comment: In my app some input box are developed in a way that in FF you for each box, 2 of them; one showed and one hidden and you have to click on the showed to digit on the real input box that is hidden, instead in Chrome i can just see the hidden already visible and digitable.